# Erro de ordenação de linha no log

Tags: c#, asp.net

Estou com uma certa dificuldade ao mostrar o log para o usuário. Mostrar as linhas de forma ordenada, porém ao mostrar aparece da seguinte forma:

Linha 5
Linha 15
Linha 11
Linha 45 
Linha 35
Linha 103

Gostaria que ficasse na seguinte ordem:

Linha 5
Linha 11
Linha 15
Linha 35 
Linha 45
Linha 103

É possível e como fazer essa ordenação a partir desse código?

```
protected void importar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
     DataTable Dados = new DataTable();
     Dados.Columns.Add("indice", typeof(int));

     int i = 1;

     foreach (DataRow linha in Dados.Rows)
     {
       linha["indice"] = i;
       i++;
     }
}

private System.Threading.Tasks.Task ProcessamentoTabela(IEnumerable<DataRow> dadosparam, int i, Usuario usuarioLogado)
{
    //usuarioLogado = aplUsuario.buscaPorLogin(ObterUsuarioAutenticado().Login);
    i = 4;
    i++;

    Action<object> processamento = (dados) =>
    {      
          if (processo != null)
          {                        
               //se o processo não for nulo busco todos procinter relacionados a ele
               List<ProcessoInteressado> listaprocinter = aplProcessoInteressado.consultarPorIdProcesso(processo.Codigo);
               if (listaprocinter.Exists(o => o.Interessado == interessado))
                    log.Append("O interessado informado na linha " + (linha["indice"]) + " foi adicionado novamente ao processo " + processo.NumProcessoJudicial + " <br>");
                    //log.Append("O interessado " + processo.Interessado.Nome + " foi adicionado novamente ao processo " + processo.NumProcessoJudicial + " <br>");
                    // log.Append("O interessado " + processo.Interessado.Nome + " foi adicionado novamente ao processo " + processo.NumProcessoJudicial + " <br>");
               setProcInter(processo, interessado, linha, i);
          }
          else
          {
               //Novo Processo - 6.3
               processo = new Processo();
          }
    }
 }
```